# Specify all the singularities of $g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on some past exam questions, and I just had a question about an intuitive way to know where the singularities of a complex function are.

For example for the function $$g(z)=\frac{1}{z^3+1}$$

The singularities are at: $z=-1$ and $z= \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{\pm \frac{i\pi}{3}}$

The root at $-1$ is obvious, but the second and the third roots at $e^{\pm \frac{i\pi}{3}}$ do not come naturally to me. How can you tell by looking at the function, what these singularities would be?

Many thanks!

Comment: The zeros of $z^3+1$, that is, the cube roots of $-1$. With a little experience, one knows them asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z_1=-1$, we have

$$(-1)^3+1=0$$

For $z_{2,3}=e^{\pm \frac{i\pi}{3}}$, we have

$$\left( e^{\pm \frac{i\pi}{3}}\right)^3+1=\left( e^{\pm (i\pi)}\right)+1=(-1)+1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The singularities in this case occur where $z^3=-1$. The solutions will form an equilateral triangle in the complex plane. It's easy to observe the $-1$ vertex of this equilateral triangle, which leads you quickly to the other two vertices $\omega_6$ and $\omega_6^5$ where $\omega_6$ indicates the $6$-th primitive [root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), (so $\omega_6=e^{2\pi i/6}$).